# How did Incredimobile know this?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-incredibles, incredibles-2

In 2018's Incredibles 2,
The incredible family moves to a "new house" offered by Winston Deavor after making a partnership with Elastigirl.

So, they've got a new house and a *new address*.

When Evelyn Deavor aka Screenslaver sends the hypnotized supers to incredibles' house to attack the kids, Dash summons IncrediMobil aka Incredibile (Mr. Incredible's car which he thought was destroyed) by pressing the Home Button on it's remote.

Now, the question is, how did this car knew where's the incredibles' new house?

Wasn't it supposed to go to their old house?

Comment: I think the car tracks the location of the control and home means wherever the control is

Comment: Consider that Mr Incredible is roaming around somewhere and wants to send the car home in case of an emergency. Now according to your point, the car will never go home because guess what, Mr Incredible must always need to keep the remote handy to control the missiles and other features of the car. If the remote's location is home for the car, then it's already home.

Comment: Why wouldn't they just have re-calibrated it when they moved?